# Some web video is not working for me browser independently. Why?

Tags: flash, video-streaming

Some flash videos are simply not working for me. One example is gamespot.com. The flash element loads, but it does not display correctly or play the video.

This also happens on other sites, for example gameone.de. However most sites, e. g. youtube.com work. Strangely, this happens with all browsers, not just my default browser (which is chrome). I am on windows 7 64.

I even tried to connect to a VPN, no change.

I suspect this is some problem with a flash setting. i tried turning off hardware acceleration, but no change. Also, I tried googling for an answer with little success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which browser and version? Which version of Flash Player?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Flash?  Have you tried in Safe Mode?  If this just started recently, have you tried using Windows' System Restore to go back to a point in time when it worked?

Comment: @iglvzx am currently using chrome 19 (the current version). Flash is also the current version. which is 11.2.202.235.

Comment: @techie007 My understanding is that chrome uses its own built-in version of flash. How can I reinstall this then? Anyway, i will try to do so for IE now.

Comment: @techie007 I reinstalled. No change. Also I cannot roll back, unfortunately, as this has happened for months.

Comment: @Johannes Can you try [Google Chrome Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable)? It installs to a single folder without touching anything else. If it works, then there is an issue with your actual Google Chrome installation. If not, then it may be a plugin or broader issue.

Comment: I finally solved this, following these instructions http://forums.adobe.com/thread/906688. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Please post and accept those instructions as an answer so that future visitors can benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this. Essentially the solution is to remove all application data for flash. Here's the instructions I followed if someone finds this post:

> Let's try the following:   Close your browser windows In Explorer, navigate to the following folder: C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\
>   (the easiest way to accomplish this is to type %appdata% in Explorer's
>   path bar.) Delete the Macromedia folder Next, go into the Adobe folder
>   and delete the "Flash Player" folder inside. Finally, go to
>   "c:\windows\system32\macromed\flash" and look for an mms.cfg file.  If
>   one is present, please rename it.   Once complete, try those offending
>   sites out again.

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/906688

Comment: Excellent! Welcome to Super User. :)