# Google Chrome can't play some flash videos

Tags: google-chrome, flash

Some flash videos won't play in Chrome, while they play perfectly in other browsers. The player will load, but instead of showing a preview of the video and a play button on the middle of the video, the screen is black:

[image: Screenshot of video that does not work]

Here's an example of a [video that does not work](http://iloveskydiving.org/view/videos/friday-freakout-first-cutaway-line-over-malfunction/#.ULjisKxQWSr) and here is a [video on the same site that does work](http://iloveskydiving.org/view/videos/friday-freakout-bow-tie-line-over-malfunction/#.ULjipaxQWSo). The video that works is a Youtube video embedded on the site with [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/about/), while the nonworking one is probably hosted by the website itself. In both cases it is using Flash. The site is popular and others don't seem to be experiencing this problem.

I am running Win7 64bit and I have no ad blockers installed.

I have found two common solutions to this problem, neither of which work:

Solution #1: [Remove all flash application data](https://superuser.com/questions/430797/some-web-video-is-not-working-for-me-browser-independently-why).

Solution #2: [Enable and disable Chrome's built in flash and System's flash](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=108086).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Chrome's Settings page: chrome://plugins/

There should be 2 Flash files listed in Plugins but Chrome disables one of them every time . ENABLE both of them: Click on Always allowed.
This works for me.

Source: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/5UjGkrHmwgM

Comment: That's precisely solution #2 which I had already tried without success.

Comment: I tried your second solution, but without the Always allowed checked. When I checked it all worked.

Comment: I've also tried disabling either Chrome's Pepper Flash and running only the system's. Right clicking on the video shows then that it is running the other flash, but the same problem persists.

Comment: I've tried the always allowed as well... strange

Comment: Did you tried this: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/889577?tstart=0 ?

Comment: Yes. I had tried that as well, except for the disabling of hardware acceleration. Tried that as well now with no success.

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble loading graphs on Yahoo Finance, they use Adobe Flash Player.

Disabling Adblock for the the site fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get any of the above to work until I went into Chrome settings and unchecked the "Use hardware acceleration when available"  It worked.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED--

1. go to settings > advanced settings > privacy > plugins > individual plugins > disable 1st adoble flsahplayer plugin

2.disable adblock for the site you are unable to watch video

hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved -- go to chrome plugins and disable the flash plugins entirely. Chrome has it's own built-in flash player. Allowing chrome to use Adobe's plugin doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I can play both videos no problem in Chrome.

Do a uninstall of Chrome and reinstall the latest version of Chrome. I suggest uninstall because if some files became corrupted for some reason, the uninstall would remove them. A reinstall (possibly a newer version) may take care of bugs and install the latest Flash player.

[image: video 1] [image: video 2]